# The inconsistent icon (logo) for blog posts

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, logo

Just noticed the change (inconsistent) between successive "refresh".

Is the logo actually *being* changed (logical) or I'm seeing some issue there?

Screenshot 1:

[image: Old one]

Screenshot 2:

[image: new one]

Comment: Seems like the bulletin is messing up where the blog should be displayed. The site icon gets used when the blog is only showing on that specific site, and the Meta SE icon gets used when the blog is showing to the entire network. When it's switching to the site icon, it's also disappearing from the bulletin across the rest of the network.